# Sc-win32-status code 3221225781

Tags: php, iis, iis-7

I'm having trouble configuring my IIS 7 server for PHP. I've configured instructions provided to the letter and have set it up on IIS express without a problem before. Can anyone shed some light on the error code or a fix as though having searched Microsoft's resources i can't find a solution.

```
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2013-09-13 13:09:28 10.19.0.241 GET /phpinfo.php - 80 - 10.19.0.77 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+5.1;+rv:23.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/23.0 500 0 3221225781 2230
```

Does anyone have any information on this code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

This *may* relate to the fact that the required Visual C++ re-distributable files are missing for this version of PHP.

As of PHP 5.5.x, I had to install the VS2012 redist (for the VC11 release).

- 32/64bit: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

If you're using the VC9 release, you'll need the VS2008 redist package:

- 32bit: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582
- 64bit: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336

Hope this helps.